# Using dynamic in Dart generics

Tags: generics, dynamic, dart

Is there any difference between `Future` and `Future<dynamic>` types in Dart language? For example, in function's return type:

```
Future f() { return ... }
```

and

```
Future<dynamic> f() { return ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Future` by itself is equivalent to `Future<dynamic>`.  However, it's not always true that `GenericClass` is always equivalent to `GenericClass<dynamic>`.  From [Fixing Common Type Problems](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/sound-problems#example-2-omitted-type-parameters-default-to-their-type-bounds):

> Consider the following **generic class** with a **bounded type parameter** that extends `Iterable`:
>
> ```
> class C<T extends Iterable> {
>   final T collection;
>   C(this.collection);
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> In Dart 2, when a generic class is instantiated without explicit type arguments, each type parameter defaults to its type bound (`Iterable` in this example) if one is explicitly given, or `dynamic` otherwise.

Also, in the case of generic functions, the type often can be inferred.